# What Build Step should be used for running QUnit tests in TeamCity?

Tags: unit-testing, msbuild, teamcity, qunit, chutzpah

I've got a TeamCity build configuration with two steps currently:

- MSBuild
- Execute powershell sciprt

I want to add another one:

- Run QUnit tests

Inside Visual Studio I use Chutzpah to run my QUnit tests. It seems that there is no "Runner type" appropriate though for QUnit tests, and because I do see one for NUnit I'm left wondering if I'm looking at this right.

Should I get a TeamCity extension to add a "Runner type" for QUnit tests? Should I create a powershell script that runs chutzpah-console? And if so how should I make sure the test output is picked up by TeamCity (do I need the `/nunit2` or `/junit` flag?)?

I've done some research, allow me to share...

I've applied my [Google-fu](https://www.google.nl/search?q=teamcity%20qunit) but that leads to [a blog post with complicated QUnit tests with special TeamCity messages](http://joseoncode.com/2011/08/09/running-qunit-tests-in-teamcity/) (or perhaps I misunderstood?) and [a blog post on using a command-line build step to call PhantomJS](http://thomasardal.com/running-qunit-tests-on-teamcity/) that uses a rather contrived html file that seems like overkill to me if I'm already using Chutzpah in Visual Studio anyways (or perhaps I misunderstood)?

I've gone through [the Chutzpah Full Documentation](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki) but as far as CI goes it only has [a section on *TFS Build*](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Running-Unit-Tests-in-a-TFS-Build), nothing on TeamCity or CI in general. I've carefully looked through [the command line options documentation](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/command-line-options), and it does have one relevant option:

> ```
> /teamcity     :Forces TeamCity mode (normally auto-detected)
> ```

This suggests that you normally don't need to do *anything* to get things working, but that's certainly not the case: my `sln` (or better: `csproj`) contains several `js` files with QUnit tests, but TeamCity shows no tests.

So, how do I get TeamCity to run QUnit tests in the (c)leanest way possible / how do I use Chutzpah in a TeamCity build step?

Comment: Well, I found the answer when nearly done writing up my question. Guessing it's probably best if I post anyway and share my solution as a self-answer, regardless of how obvious it may be to some (AFAIK this answer wasn't out there / easy to find yet). - And perhaps someone will chime in with an even better solution!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for "service messges" or custom html files that go into a special PhantomJS call if you're already using Chutzpah. Here's one (other) way to do it in a (c)lean way.

**There is no specific runner type for this type of build step.** But no need for a custom Powershell script either: it'll be one line of script only. You can just use a `Command Line` step to invoke Chutzpah. To be more complete, assuming you've got TeamCity running already on a Windows machine, follow these steps:

1. Install `chutzpah.console.exe`. The easiest way is probably using [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) to install the [Chutzpah package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/chutzpah) using this command in Powershell:

   ```
   choco install chutzpah
   ```

   This installs Chutzpah and makes sure the `exe` is in your path (you may need to reboot TeamCity parts to get this noticed!).

   Note that alternatively you could also manually get `chutzpah.console.exe` on your CI server somehow (e.g. grab it from your dev machine) and reference it with a full path or place it in your path yourself.
2. Add a `Command Line` build step with a custom script like this:

   ```
   chutzpah.console.exe "MyProject/UnitTestsSubDir"
   ```

   E.g.:

   [image: Build step configuration in TeamCity]

And by some black magic this is all it takes: your tests will be run (see the build log) and TeamCity will pick up the test results.